# Function to take an Html structure and call it whenever we want to display that dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 3 pages that contains some blocks with the same structure.  I don't want to repeat the same code several times, so what I want to do is a function that stock an html structure and which I call everytime I need to display that part of HTML dynamically. Not sure how to do it correctly
data is coming from JSON Object.

This is what I tried to do :

```
function generateHtml() {
    var generateContent = '';
    generateContent += '<div id="blockAlarme" name="blockAlarme" clas="clsBlock">';
    generateContent += '<div id="blockAlarmeHeader" name="blockAlarmeHeader" class="clsBlockHeader">';
    generateContent += '<div class="clsBlockHeaderTitle">Alarme</div>';
    generateContent += '<div class="clsBlockHeaderReduce"></div>';
    generateContent += '</div>';
    generateContent += '<div id="blockAlarmeContent" name="blockAlarmeContent" class="clsBlockContent"></div>';
    generateContent += '</div>';
}
```

And then I have to call it inside an html code that is appended by Ajax so that it displays content.

Comment: ajax *is* JQuery: it's part of the JQuery library.

Comment: @JackParkinson Yes i know but i mean by that should i use ajax call because i'm working with json or just a simple jquery call.. don't know if i'm clear

Comment: Wait, what are you doing with the JSON? What does the JSON contribute to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using web components, here is a nice article: https://toddmotto.com/web-components-concepts-shadow-dom-imports-templates-custom-elements/

However, you could also use JQuery to do something like this:

```js
var alarmData = [
  {name: "Alarm 1",text: "This is an alarm"},
  {name: "Blue Alarm",text:"BEEP BEEP BEEP"}
];

$.each(alarmData, function(i, alarm) { 
    var block = $('<div/>', {
      class: 'clsBlock'
    }).appendTo($('#container'));
    
    var header = $('<div/>', {
      class: 'clsBlockHeader',
      html: alarm.name
    }).appendTo(block);
    
    var content = $('<div/>', {
      class: 'clsBlockContent',
      html: alarm.text
    }).appendTo(block);
});
```

```css
.clsBlock {
width: 200px; height: 100px;
border: 1px solid blue;
margin: 5px;
}
.clsBlockHeader {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the snippet to use a JSON object since it seems that may be where your data is coming from.  More information might be useful though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is exactly what i wanted to achieve, yes indeed my data is coming from a JSON file, didn"t know it would be useful to know..all i was thinking about is the html structure...just a question please , why do you use div like this '<div/>' ? and not just <div> ?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757482/creating-an-empty-element-with-start-tag-vs-self-closing-tag